# how to get transform-origin properties separated

Tags: javascript

I want to get transform-origin properties separated in JavaScript

but I don't know how to do it

**JavaScript:**

```
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(myElement).getPropertyValue("transform-origin"))
```

should I change "transform-origin" to something else?

Comment: You can separate them by splitting the value string on the empty space with ```yourMyElementValue.split(" ")```

Comment: Something like `const [ x, y, z ] = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue("transform-origin").split(" "); console.log({ x, y, z });`?